# Mocking Httpcalls always return NullPointerException

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, httprequest

I'm trying to mock Http calls for unit test.
To do that I have done the following, I have created a RequestMock case class:

```
case class RequestMock() {
  def sendRequest(httpRequest: HttpRequest)(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem): Future[HttpResponse] = {
    Http().singleRequest(httpRequest)
  }
}
```

and in my service, I have written the following piece of code :

```
case class Service(requestHandler: RequestMock) {
....
for {
  response <- {
        requestHandler.sendRequest(
          HttpRequest(
            method = HttpMethods.GET,
            uri = "http://database:9000"
          )
        )
  } yield {
   response
}

}
```

For the unit test, I'm trying to mock HttpCalls, to do that, I have done the following :

```
def test_2 = mock[RequestMock]
```

And for defining the mock behaviour I have done the following

```
      when(test_2.sendRequest(
        HttpRequest(
          method = HttpMethods.GET,
          uri = "http://database:9000")
      )).thenReturn{
        Future(
          HttpResponse(
            StatusCodes.OK,
            entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`,"connection established"))
```

But, when I execute unit tests, I always get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue ?

Comment: Where do you get the exception? Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: yes, I got the error in  requestHandler.sendRequest

Comment: Could you provide more test lines? How do you create the `Service` object in your test? Do you pass the mocked request into the `Service`?

Comment: Well I a service class have, which is defined like this:

```case class Service(requestHandler: RequestMock)  {
          def getDatabase{
                   for {
  response <- {
        requestHandler.sendRequest(
          HttpRequest(
            method = HttpMethods.GET,
            uri = "http://database:9000"
          )
        )
  } yield {
   response
}
```

and I have route class:

```case class ServiceRoute(sendRequest: RequestMock)  {
  def getAdWeeksRoute: Route = path("database" ) {
    get {
               service.getDatabase
    }
  }
```

Comment: and for the test class: 
```
  def httpRequestMock = mock[RequestMock]
  val  databaseRoutes = ServiceRoute(httpRequestMock)
  private val routes = Route.seal(databaseRoutes .routes)
```

Comment: ```
           when(httpRequestMock.sendRequest(
              HttpRequest(
                method = HttpMethods.GET,
                uri = s"http://database:9000")
            )).thenReturn{
              println("mock received request")
              Future(
                HttpResponse(
                  StatusCodes.OK,
                  entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`,"expected_output")))
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems.
First of all, `test_2` should be a `val`, not a `def`.
With `def` like you have it, you get a different instance every time you access it. So,  you define the stub on one instance,  but then create your `Service` with a different one, that does not have `sendRequest` defined, so returns `null` by default, and that causes your `NPE`.

The next problem, that you will probably encounter after you fix this one is that you are not defining *all* of the behavior.

```
when(test_2.sendRequest(
        HttpRequest(
          method = HttpMethods.GET,
          uri = "http://database:9000")
      ))
```

Only creates a stub for a method call with *this specific parameter value*. So, if your tests try to make a `POST` for example or hit a different endpoint, you'll get an NPE again.

Even if you only ever use one request, it is better to define the stub for *any* argument, to avoid weird NPE failures if the code happens to send a different one (you are writing a *test*, so should not just assume automatically, that the code will always do what you expect - you would not need the test in the first place if that was the case):

```
when(test2.sendRequest(any)),thenReturn(Future.successful(...))
```

(Note `Future.successful` above – that's the correct way to create `Future` that is immediately satisfied, what  you are doing makes it run on a thread ... not a big deal in your case, but still icky).

Then, after the test code is run, you can check that the parameter value passed to the `sendRequest` was actually what you expect:

```
verify(test2)
  .sendRequest(HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.GET, uri = "http://database:9000"))
```